# How to check if a movieclip has stopped rotating/spinning

Tags: flash, actionscript-2, flash-cs6

I have a script where I press a button called `spin_btn`and once it is released it spins a wheel. Here is the AS for `spin_btn`:

```
spin_btn.onRelease = function()
{
    speed = randomRange(25, 900);
    spinning = true;

    if (spinning)
    {
    spin_btn._visible = false;
    }

};
```

Here is the AS that makes the wheel spin:

```
_root.onEnterFrame = function()
{
    spinning = true;
    if (spinning)
    {
        spinner_bg.spinner_wheel._rotation += speed;
        speed = speed * drag;

        if (Math.pow(speed, 2) < .0001)
        {
            speed = 0;
        }
    }
};
```

This is what I have tried inside the `spin_btn` function:

```
spin_btn.onRelease = function()
{
    speed = randomRange(25, 900);
    spinning = true;
    if (spinning)
    {
        spin_btn._visible = false;
    }
    else if (!spinning)
    {
        gotoAndStop(2);
    }
};
```

However once the wheel stops spinning, it doesn't go to frame 2 and i'm not too sure why. If anyone could help me out, then that would be great. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to move frame as soon as the wheel stops, you need to put the `gotoAndStop(2);` where you're currently setting the speed to 0

```
if (Math.pow(speed, 2) < .0001)
{
    speed = 0;
    gotoAndStop(2);
}
```

Also look at what your `spinning` variable is doing. You're setting it to `true` on the button release, but you're also setting it to `true` in `onEnterFrame` and you're not setting it to `false` anywhere so it doesn't really do anything at all. Currently you are controlling the wheel purely by setting the `speed` variable since `spinning` is always `true`